# Python3 : Remove Arabic Punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm working in Arabic text , I want to remove the Arabic Punctuation 
Example :

```
s="أهلاً بالعالم في هذه التجربة ! علامات ،الترقيم ؟ ,? لا .اتذكرها"
```

I want the output to remove `" ؟ ، "` also because when I use:

```
import string
tr= str.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)
```

the output was `'أهلاً بالعالم في هذه التجربة  علامات ،الترقيم ؟ لا اتذكرها'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `string.punctuation` constant contains only the punctuation characters defined in ASCII, which does not even cover all signs used with the Latin script (eg. "fancy quotes" like «» are missing).

If you don't want to create a list of all punctuation characters yourself (I wouldn't), you can use the [Unicode character property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) to decide if a character is punctuation or not.
The built-in `unicodedata` module gives you access to this information:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> for c in 'abc: قيم ؟':
...     print((c, ud.category(c))
a Ll
b Ll
c Ll
: Po
  Zs
ق Lo
ي Lo
م Lo
  Zs
؟ Po
```

All categories are two-letter codes, like "Ll" for "letter, lowercase" or "Po" for "punctuation, other".
All punctuation characters have a category that starts with "P".

You can use this information for filtering out punctuation characters (eg. using a generator expression):

```
>>> s = "أهلاً بالعالم في هذه التجربة ! علامات ،الترقيم ؟ ,? لا .اتذكرها"
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if not ud.category(c).startswith('P'))
'أهلاً بالعالم في هذه التجربة  علامات الترقيم   لا اتذكرها'
```

Answer (score 6):

I was working on a similar issue and came across this post. Here is what I used to solve it. Hope this helps.

```
s="أهلاً بالعالم في هذه التجربة ! علامات ،الترقيم ؟ ,? لا .اتذكرها"

new_s = s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '?؟ً')) # add punctuation here

print(new_s)
```